# Как сделать авто-обновление страницы по таймингу? PHP

Tags: php, битрикс

Например есть страница `index.php` находится на пути

```
/var/www/vhosts/supply.com/httpdocs/supply-dev/test1/index.php
```

Как обращаться к этой странице и обновлять ее автоматически 2 раза в день с интервалом?

Comment: вы имеете ввиду ваш скрипт запускать? в Битре для этого задачи есть, их можно на крон повесить

Comment: @Orange_shadow да скрипт запускать, все правильно поняли. Но мои знания крона сейчас на нуле((

Comment: Ну тогда в поиске вибвай установка планировщика крон и вперед, таких вопросов 1000 на stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

В начало вашего `PHP` кода. `10` число кол-во секунд до обновления.

```
 header('refresh: 10');
```

Переход по "`any.php`" через 10 секунд.

```
header('refresh: 10;url=any.php');
```

На `JS`

```
<script>
    window.rld=function()
    {window.location.href="http://site.ru" }
    window.setTimeout("rld()",100)
</script>
```

Comment: фоново если я не нахожусь на странице обновляться будет если я не нахожусь на странице

Comment: @ЕвгенийПивоваров немного не понял вашего вопроса, если это вопрос. Расставьте правильно знаки препинания

Comment: прошу прощения, спешил(( Фоново будет работать какой нибудь из способов, не заходя на страницу index.php?

Comment: @ЕвгенийПивоваров JS будет работать всегда, не зависимо, находитесь ли вы на вкладке или нет.

Comment: Если закрыть браузер -- работать не будет.

Comment: @Andrewus вопрос стоял не о том, будет ли обновляться если закрыть браузер.

Comment: "Как обращаться к этой странице и обновлять ее автоматически 2 раза в день с интервалом?" - вот такой вопрос стоял.
Я так понял из вопроса, что вы хотите, чтобы эта страница сама как-то вызывалась два раза в день, без вашего участия. И держать открытую вкладку в браузере -- не лучший метод решения такой проблемы. Притом, что некоторые браузеры останавливают выполнение скриптов в неактивных вкладках.

Answer (score 0):

а для чего? не очень понятно.

если нужно обновлять без участия людей, то на `cron` можно повесить, либо попробовать на Агентах, там нужно будет в `init.php` заинклюдить файл `/var/www/vhosts/supply.com/httpdocs/supply-dev/test1/index.php`